# Creating default custom Hystrix Property

Tags: annotations, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

I'm new on Hystrix, I'm just adding it to my project, but I'd like to know whether I can create a custom annotation "HystrixDefaultTimeoutProperty" that extends the HystrixProperty, so each time I want to use a default value for the timeout I can use that custom annotation instead of using:

```
@HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "5000")
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible, If you were to look at the source code of `HystrixCommand`  and `@HystrixProperty`

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface HystrixCommand {
  .....
}
```

and

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface HystrixProperty {
  .....
}
```

Both of these annotations has

> @Target({ElementType.METHOD})

which implies you can use these annotations only on Methods

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid there were no chance of doing that